# vacuum do not scan all blocks on a database

Tags: postgresql

I loaded data into an empty database. Before loading, the autovacuum parameter is set to off.
At the end of the loading this parameter is set back to on.
The database is 58Gb. In the vacuum statistics view pg_stat_progress_vacuum the heap_blks_total is 505714 so we have:

```
size (kb) = 505714 * 8 = 4045712
```

Why is only 4Gb scanned by the vacuum while the database is 10 time larger?

Comment: Read [Autovacuum daemon](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html) for the settings that cause the autovacuum daemon to run. A load is essentially INSERTS and they don't need vacuuming. It is UPDATEs and DELETEs that create the tuples that need to be vacuumed. There is also the process that runs to prevent [transaction id wraparound](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND). After loading it would be a good idea to run a manual [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html)  to update the table statistics.

Comment: pg_stat_progress_vacuum.heap_blks_total shows the tables currently being vacuumed not the cumulative sum of all action.

Comment: @jjanes The documentation suggests otherwise...

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Since v13, inserts also trigger autovacuum.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, missed that I stand corrected. Still in this case the `autovacuum` was turned off during the import so it would not have 'seen' them, correct? Any activity at that point would have been due to transaction id wraparound protection.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The statistics still get collected , even if autovacuum is turned off.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The pg_stat_progress_vacuum view is clearly per-table and once a table is no longer being vacuumed, nothing shows up for it anymore.  I don't see anything in the docs suggesting otherwise.

Comment: @jjanes I see the light now. I had assumed that OP was talking about a single table, but of course a database consists of several tables.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver If the inserts do not trigger a vacuum then why are 4Gb scanned by this process. I think the value of the heap_blks_total field corresponds to the processing performed by a vacuum worker at a given time for specifics tables. After modifying the autovacuum parameter to on many wals are generated which means that the vacuum writes in the header of the blocks or that of the tuples. But what flag is the vacuum changing or what information is it writing?

Comment: 1) As @LaurenzAlbe pointed out I was wrong about INSERTs not triggering autovacuum for Postgres 13. Are you using Postgres 13+? 2) At the time you did the original INSERTs autovacuum was off anyway, so what you are seeing is activity after the original import. That could be coming from either autovacuum or manual vacuums. In the case of autovacuum that would be activity driven based on number of insert/update/delete actions.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes it is PG13. Thanks for your comment